# How to specify IP of docker container in Marathon?

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

We can map docker container port to host machine IP and port using

```
docker run -d -p <some-ip>:<port>:<port> --name <some-name> <docker-image>
```

But how to specify host machine IP while deploying the same container using Marathon? Where should I specify the IP of host machine in Marathon app spec? For my requirement specifying host IP is a necessity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Marathon [constraints](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/constraints.html) to influence the placement of your app but I'd suggest that a better, more forward-looking way is not to pin an app to a certain node (what if this node fails?) but use [service discovery](https://github.com/mhausenblas/dcos-sd) to dynamically figure out the IP and the port the app is serving on.

Comment: What if I deploy my docker container using host mode and not the bridge mode? What aspects of running container would and wouldn't be isolated from the host machine in that case?

Comment: And, @t6nand: if you have additional questions, start a new one. This tagging onto an existing question is bad and not useful for people coming after you.